# Are Christians monotheists and what is the nature of Jesus? (i.e. Give me the basics of Christianity please)

Tags: life-of-jesus

I am not familiar with Christianity so I have some questions.

1- Is Jesus one and only god? I have read some other questions and answers and I have found that there is a real God and Jesus is his son and Jesus is also a god. Isn't it illogical I mean there are 2 god and they have infinite power.

2- Is there any other god except two of them?

3- If Jesus is a God then how people killed him? Why he let people to kill?

4- How jesus was born? Is real god create him? If answer is yes can he create more gods?

These are my questions for now. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Hi @hellzone - A lot of this is already covered on the site, but I'd really like to answer you, so I'm going to put this into an answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your question is not a single question but a series of questions.  Some of those question are truth questions which do not conform to this SE.  Please read [FAQ].  It is difficult to understand what is actually being asked in your "question".

Comment: Please note, I'm not the downvoter, but as a sign to others, normally we don't do this.  I'm just feeling kind of generous today.

Comment: Also, you might get a kick out of knowing that just about everyting I wrote was originally worked out in your country of Turkey.  Izmir is the old Nicea, from which the term "Nicene Christianity" is derived.

Comment: All your questions are interesting but you have to ask one at a time. We can't cover everything at one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>This answer will mostly link to other answers already on the site - please understand that I'm really taking this as a basic "Give me the basics of Christianity."  Please understand, normally this would be off-topic, as we are really more geared to experts, but I think having one basic answer here is helpful.</sup>

This answer really needs to explain the two big points of Christianity:

1. What is the Nature of God, and
2. What is the Nature of Jesus.

These two things are both as basic as it gets and hard to understand for non-Christians. As such, putting them in one place helps to define what Christians believe.

<sup>Note: This is stuff that *[all Nicene (read "Mainstream") Christians - Catholic, Orthodox, and Protestant](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/884/1039)* believe at one level (+ or - a few very small fringe groups <2%) at a basic level, although there may be nuances in the particulars.  The only real exceptions are those deemed 'heretical' since 325 or a few modern splinter groups, of which the Jehovah's Witness and LDS churches would be the largest outliers.</sup>

**What is the Nature of God?** (Answer: Trinitarian)

> 1- Is Jesus one and only god?

In classic, Nicene Christianity, we believe in "The Trinity," namely that God the Father, God the Son (Jesus), and the Holy Spirit are three persons but also one.  While it seems illogical, it's not really - it's just that there is no good metaphor to explain it.  The Athansian Creed puts it as such:

> "we worship one God in Trinity, and Trinity in Unity; Neither confounding the Persons; nor dividing the Essence. For there is one Person of the Father; another of the Son; and another of the Holy Ghost. But the Godhead of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost, is all one; the Glory equal, the Majesty coeternal."

For more, see

[What is the Doctrine of the Trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/13655/1039)

[Is God Three or One?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/8883/1039)

> 2- Is there any other god except two of them?

Again, please see what the Trinity is - it isn't two (or three) but one, even though they have different personalities.

**What is the Nature of Jesus? (Christology)** (Answer: Hypostatic Union)

> 3- If Jesus is a God then how people killed him? Why he let people to kill?

Classically, Jesus is "[fully god and fully man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union)".  If he is not God, then he has sins of his own for which he must pay. If he is not man, he is not an acceptable sacrifice. As both God and man, he can subject himself to death as He desires, and overcome it as well.

As to 'why did he let them kill him?'  The classic answer is John 3:16 -

> For God so *loved* the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosever should believe in Him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

Along with that are several models of salvation, all of which seek to answer why it is that God required the death of his son to "[satisfy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_theory_of_atonement)" or "[atone for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitutionary_atonement)" the sins of a fallen humanity, or if there was simple some "[victory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christus_Victor)" that had to be won.

For more see

[Was Jesus created?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/7797/1039)

[Why did Jesus have to be fully God and Fully Man?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19458/why-does-jesus-have-to-be-fully-god-and-fully-man-is-it-not-sufficient-to-be-th)

> 4- How jesus was born? Is real god create him? If answer is yes can he create more gods?

Jesus wasn't "born" he was begotten.  Per John 1, He was from the beginning - and "without Him was nothing made that was made."  He was incarnated - meaning he became man - in Palestine around 4BC, lived, died on a cross, and was resurrected.

He sent the Holy Spirit, but does not "beget" more gods because God already is - he is eternal.

Comment: I'm surprised that you answered these questions.

Comment: I think it is kind and gracious to give a starting point to everybody - even if it's not exactly what we do here.

Comment: Yeah, I started answering the questions in a comment then felt it wasn't proper.  Good job extending the olive branch while being willing to extend the boundaries of the site.

Comment: @AffableGeek 1- I really don't get "The Trinity". You are saying "There are 3 gods but also there is only one god but nobody can explain it....". You mean there is only one god but he is using jesus, real god's and holy sprit's forms?

Comment: Read the links.  Your answer doesn't fit in a comment :) Also "real god" isn't really an applicable term.

Comment: @ hellzone you may want to go to the following website where you can ask all the questions you have, but most questions have been asked about what Christianity is and most other questions regarding God etc. that site is http//www.Christianity.net.au

Comment: @hellzone The Trinity is one of the most difficult doctrines of Christianity to explain even for systematic theologians who study this extensively. It's similar to the problem of defining the word chair. It's far easier for me to show you than to tell you. In this case, showing you requires you to accept the Trinity on faith and experience how God works in your life. I hate pulling the divine revelation card but it's the best I can do. Other than that you're stuck with AffableGeek's links.

Answer (score 2):

**Christianity for beginners**

Christianity is a **monotheistic** religion. There is only one God and He has **three parts/personalities - Father, Word and Spirit**. God created everything through the Word and by the power of the Spirit. The last and most important creation recorded in the Bible was **Adam and Eve**, the first couple on earth. They disobeyed God's warning by eating a forbidden fruit, motivated by the tempting words of a serpent. **Sin and Death entered the world** through them and everyone born from them are now sinful. Man was perfect at the creation but now is sinful and cannot change himself.

God then selected the descendants of **Abraham** the patriarch and promised them through many prophets that He will send a deliverer, the **Messiah**. God then sent His Word as the Messiah and call Him **His Son**, who was born from a virgin and was given a human name, Jesus. **Jesus fulfilled the prophecies by dying on the cross for us**. Jesus gave His life for us to pay the penalty of our sins because the penalty for sin is death. God raised Jesus from the dead after three days and is now sitting at the right hand of God, interceding for us and acts as a mediator between God and man.

**Jesus will come again** to judge the world and gather those who believe in Him to Heaven. There will be a **Judgement Day** for all souls and those who believe Jesus will enter Heaven and those who don't will be thrown into the Lake of Fire. After this, God will destroy the earth and create a **new earth**, far far better than the present one and those justified through Jesus will live there forever.

Comment: Reads like a [creed](http://www.ccel.org/creeds/apostles.creed.html)... and a very good one at that!

Comment: Could I suggest not using "parts" or "personalities" but rather "persons"? Technically, parts is the heresy of partialism, and personalities is Nestorian.

Comment: @AffableGeek I don't know why but I just feel uncomfortable in using "persons" because it sounds like three Gods. The Bible never uses 'parts', 'personalities' or 'persons' anyway. I think we have the liberty to use whatever terms we like.

Comment: Three persons and one essence are just historical terms. Obviously you have liberty to write whatever you'd like :) but the classic formulations use those terms and have very precise meanings.